# pyodbc Driver keyword syntax error

Tags: syntax, driver, keyword, pyodbc

My conn_str that is passed into pyodbc.connect(conn_str) is:

```
conn_str = str("DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}};" + 
"server=...;database=...;" + "APP=Entity Mapping 
Lookup;UID=svc_infra_jobs;PWD=...").
```

The `=...` next to server and database actually contain names, that is not the problem here.

When i try to do: `temp = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)`, I get the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM012', '[IM012] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
DRIVER keyword syntax error (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my DRIVER keyword.

Comment: Try removing the curly brackets altogether. They aren't necessary for that driver name.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the curly brackets solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but figured out that for some driver managers the DSN name length can't exceed 32 characters.
https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB44110-quot-Data-source-name-is-longer-than-32-characters-quot?language=en_US